# php code that add data from form with input type="file" in text file in JSON format

Tags: php, html

```
    // path and name of the file
$filetxt = 'http://alkha.com/codecall/formdata.txt';

    // check if all form data are submited, else output error message
    if(isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['uploadedimage'])) {
    // if form fields are empty, outputs message, else, gets their data
    if(empty($_POST['title']) || empty($_POST['uploadedimage'])) {
        echo 'All fields are required';
    }
    else {
    // gets and adds form data into an array
    $data = array(
      'title'=> $_POST['title'],
      'uploadedimage'=> $_POST['uploadedimage'],

    );

    // path and name of the file
    $filetxt = 'http://alkha.com/codecall/formdata.txt';

    $arr_data = array();        // to store all form data

    // check if the file exists
    if(file_exists($filetxt)) {
      // gets json-data from file
      $jsondata = file_get_contents($filetxt);

      // converts json string into array
      $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    }

    // appends the array with new form data
    $arr_data[] = $data;

    // encodes the array into a string in JSON format (JSON_PRETTY_PRINT - uses whitespace in json-string, for human readable)
    $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    // saves the json string in "data.txt" (in "dirdata" folder)
    // outputs error message if data cannot be saved
    if(file_put_contents($filetxt, $jsondata)) echo 'Data successfully saved';
    else echo 'Tidak dapat menyimpan data di "dirdata/data.txt"';
  }
}
    else echo 'Form fields not submited';
?>
```

*I upload image and put text in text field but This message display "Form fields not submited",I would like to write image path in text file with json, but i think the value in the input type= "file" field disappears*

Comment: Check that this condition evaluates to true: `if(isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['uploadedimage'])) {` ! You might add var_dump($_POST); to the top in order to see whats incomming via a POST request. And btw. ask a question.. just guessing around here.

Comment: Also don't forget that uploaded files are not access with the `$_POST` array, they show up in the `$_FILES` array. Make sure your form is capable of sending files `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.this problem was fixed, but there is another errors   `Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /home/content/81/11702381/html/codecall/saveimage.php on line 39

Warning: file_put_contents(http://alkhawarzmi.com/codecall/formdata.txt) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in /home/content/81/11702381/html/codecall/saveimage.php on line 43
Tidak dapat menyimpan data di "dirdata/data.txt"`